# Can't call a JPanel within a JPanel's button

Tags: button, jpanel

Done a search and I really didn't see a matched answer with this tricky problem.

Here I come, guys. Thanks for your help in advance.

I am trying to call a JPanel within a JPanel's button by using actionlistener;
while it worked fine with the first button I added, it doesn't work for the other two;
the difference between the jpanels called in first button and the rest two is that, 
the first button calling another Jpanel out of current Jpanel; but the other two calling
two private-classed jpanel within current Jpanels.

What I am doing: I am trying display two different charts within the same Jpanel using
two buttons, interchangeably; the private jpanels are purely used for drawing charts; I thought I only need to call the these two jpanels in different buttons without creating a totally new JPanel to
contain each jpanel to draw a chart, and then call them like I call the another jpanel in the first button.

apologise for my awkward wording..here are the codes.

> public class ExamPerf extends JPanel {
>
> final JPanel viewPerf = TabbedQuiz.viewPerfPanel;
>
> final ChartsPanel CP = new ChartsPanel();

//I am building up the jpanel in its constructor; all the buttons are in here;

```
          public ExamPerf() {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    setBounds(0, 0, 728, 380);
    setLayout(null);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 10));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE),
            "Exam Performance", 0, 0, new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15),
            Color.WHITE));

    DrawCurrent drawarea=new DrawCurrent();
    add(drawarea);
```

// this is the first button, calling another Jpanel, a completely different class;

```
    JButton backBut = new JButton("Main Menu");
    backBut.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    backBut.setBounds(10, 24, 93, 23);
    add(backBut);
    backBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setVisible(false);
            invalidate();
            viewPerf.add(CP);

        }
    });
```

//this is the second button, I am trying to call the private class DrawCurrent;
//but it doesn't work; my thought was,

```
    JButton histoPerf = new JButton("Historical Performance");
    histoPerf.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    histoPerf.setBounds(122, 24, 161, 23);
    add(histoPerf);
    histoPerf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setVisible(false);

            invalidate();

            DrawCurrent drawplace=new DrawCurrent();


            add(drawplace, BorderLayout.CENTER);




        }
    });
```

//this is third button, same problem.

> ```
>           JButton currentPerf = new JButton("Current Performance");
>     currentPerf.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
>     currentPerf.setBounds(303, 24, 151, 23);
>     add(currentPerf);
>     currentPerf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
> ```

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setVisible(true);
            invalidate();

            DrawHistorical drawHis=new DrawHistorical();
            add(drawHis);




        }
    });

}
```

// this is the first private class, DrawCurrent;

> public class DrawCurrent extends JPanel {

```
    public DrawCurrent() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(null);

        setBounds(10, 49, 708, 320);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 10));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE), "Chart", 0,
                0, new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15), Color.WHITE));
        setLayout(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        final Graphics2D canvas = (Graphics2D) g;
        final BasicStroke Pen = new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);

        canvas.setStroke(Pen);
        canvas.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        canvas.drawLine(5, 315, 703, 315);
        canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 700, getWidth() / 2, 19);

        // write the names of columns on top of them;
        canvas.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));
        canvas.drawString("Right", 50, 100);
        canvas.drawString("Wrong", getWidth() / 2 + 150, 300);

        // draw two 3D rectangles as the columns of the performances;
        //
        canvas.fill3DRect(50, 100, 40, 215, true);
        canvas.fill3DRect(getWidth() / 2 + 150, 300, 40, 15, true);

    }

}
```

// this is the second private class, DrawHistorical;

> private class DrawHistorical extends JPanel {

```
    final ArrayList<Integer> examCount=new ArrayList<>();

    final int leftEdge=10;

    public DrawHistorical() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(null);

        setBounds(leftEdge, 49, 708, 320);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 10));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE), "Chart", 0,
                0, new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15), Color.WHITE));
        setLayout(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        final Graphics2D canvas = (Graphics2D) g;
        final BasicStroke Pen = new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);

        canvas.setStroke(Pen);
        canvas.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        canvas.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));

        //this loop is to draw the graph of the historical performance of completed exams.
        for(int i=0; i<examCount.size();i=i+3){

            // write the number of exam on top of the lien graph.

        canvas.drawString("Ex"+examCount.get(i).toString(), leftEdge+i, examCount.get(i));

            // draw the line graph and extends as long as the number of completed exams increases.

        canvas.drawLine(leftEdge+2+i, examCount.get(i), leftEdge+3+i, examCount.get(i+1));

        }



    }

}
```

Thank you very much guys, anything not clear please throw them at me.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are some rules here - I am here for so long that I dunno them by heart :) - but I remember to something called SSCE. A simple, self-contained example, which ensures that you get lots of answers from everyone.

1) The actual problem is that you create new panels right in the action listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    setVisible(false);
    invalidate();
    DrawCurrent drawplace=new DrawCurrent();
    add(drawplace, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

and do strange things here.

1) setVisible(false) will hide something from the screen - not the panel I presume, but likely the outer panel.

2) you create a new DrawCurrent instance, and add to the layout, instead of hiding the other panel and making this panel visible.

The right logic is: create both the DrawCurrent and DrawHistorical instances at once in the ExamPerf class, add add to its layout:

```
DrawCurrent current;
DrawHistorical historical;

public ExamPerf() extends JPanel {
    current=new DrawCurrent();
    historical=new Historical();
    add(current); // TODO you may need further layout settings here
    add(historical);  // TODO you may need further layout settings here
    current.setVisible(true);
    historical.setVisible(false);
}
```

And in the button listeners, just change visible properties of the *chart* panels:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    current.setVisible(false); 
    history.setVisible(true);
}
```

(and same for the other button, which makes true and false to show the other panel).

---

Alternatively, instead of implementing your own workaround, consider using CardLayout which is designed to solve this out of the box.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html